# Custom meta-box > 18+ pop-up confirmation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

My first post here.

I would like to ask if anyone can take a look at this.

**How it should be like:** I want custom meta-box containing checkbox in Wordpress administration while creating a new page. If I check this checkbox and publish the page and someone will want to see it, pop-up 18+ confirmation will appear.

- This should be a plugin or take place in Functions.

I am trying to figure out how to connect it or make it assign an attribute which will have pop-up confirmatiion built-in.

**Here is what I have so far: (thanks to wordpress codex)**

```
function adult_add_meta_box() {

    $screens = array( 'post', 'page' );

    foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {

        add_meta_box(
            'adult_sectionid',__( 'Adult content', 'adult_textdomain' ), 'adult_meta_box_callback', $screen, 'side' );
    }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'adult_add_meta_box' );

/**
 * Prints the box content.
 * 
 * @param WP_Post $post The object for the current post/page.
 */
function adult_meta_box_callback( $post ) {

    // Add an nonce field so we can check for it later.
    wp_nonce_field( 'adult_meta_box', 'adult_meta_box_nonce' );

    /*
     * Use get_post_meta() to retrieve an existing value
     * from the database and use the value for the form.
     */
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key', true );

    echo '<label for="adult_new_field">';
    _e( '<input type="checkbox" name="Adult" value="adult-content">' . " 18+" );
    echo '</label> ';
}

/**
 * When the post is saved, saves our custom data.
 *
 * @param int $post_id The ID of the post being saved.
 */
function adult_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {

    /*
     * We need to verify this came from our screen and with proper authorization,
     * because the save_post action can be triggered at other times.
     */

    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['adult_meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['adult_meta_box_nonce'], 'adult_meta_box' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }

    } else {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    /* OK, it's safe for us to save the data now. */

    // Make sure that it is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['adult_new_field'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Sanitize user input.
    $my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['adult_new_field'] );

    // Update the meta field in the database.
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_meta_value_key', $my_data );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'adult_save_meta_box_data' );

?>
```

As you can see, it is chaos so far.
I will appreciate ANY help or improvement.

Comment: Hi, I'm using your code snippet. May I ask  `$value = get_post_meta()` what `$value` is used for? I dont see you use that value anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Advanced Custom Fields -plugin for making metabox for pages and posts. You can read more about ACF on their website http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/.

For this `Adult page` input you may want to check this one http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/true-false/

With advanced custom fields you can create those metaboxes on admin panel quite easily. For example you could create checkbox labeled `Adult page` which have key `adult_page`. Then you could open your theme header.php and add this:

```
<?php if ( get_field( "adult_page" ) ) : ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        if ( window.confirm( 'Are you older than 18?' ) ) {
            // user pressed 'ok'
        } else {
            // user pressed 'cancel'
        }

    </script>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Are you serious? :D Thanks! I was trying to figure this out for like hours and you came in like a clever-ball.

Thanks for the answer. It works fine.

I am just wondering, is it ideal to include PHP element based on that one you wrote into the header.php?

Or is there another way how to include field_check into the website's functionality?

Comment: It really depends. I would make it like this: hide page content with CSS if field `adult_page` is set to true. Then show styled javascript popup (you can use http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ for example) which does display some text (You need to confirm you are older than 18...etc) and if user confirm, you show the page content by changing CSS with javascript. Header.php is ok place to add this, but you need to be careful. On archive page, if first post/page has field `adult_page` set to true, archive page has field `adult_page` set to true.